# How to store an sql query string in a field of a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a log table which logs actions that affect the database, and I store the sql statements in a field called details.

Below is an example query where I try to insert a row into my log table but I run into problems with the details part, as I am inserting a query into the field and mysql interprets it as part of the actual query and errors

```
INSERT INTO `user_log` SET `log_dts`='2012-05-28 15:07:19', `user_id`='4', `details`='UPDATE `property` SET `timedeleted` = '2012-05-28 15:07:19' WHERE `propertyid` IN (1594930)'
```

How is it best to handle this?

Thanks.

edit: to add, the details field is a text field in the mysql db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_string - d'uh

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotation marks in your string.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an escape character to the "'", just replace all occurrences of ' in the query with \'.